# Matlab: Accurate thresholding with a shadow-striped image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

My image has an object is covered by a series of thin stripes of shadows (imagine a dog lying in the shade of a skinny fence on a sunny day). I would like to binarize this image so that only the parts that are not in shadow are white.

I've tried graythresh() with im2bw() but I end up with white patches spreading across the shadowed portions. I think you can somewhat get an idea of what the desired output should be from this:

[image]
[image]

Is there a better thresholding procedure for making the black stripes clearer?

EDIT: I forgot to include the original. For some reason the color changed when it uploaded.

Comment: Do you get any better results by varying the level in im2bw()?

Comment: please post the original image as well.

Comment: @Ben: I originally used a constant value for the level, but passing in graythresh(img) works much better, though not good enough yet.

Comment: You must upload the input image again. It is quantized and color-distorted. please use the original input image and not a saves figure.